# Convert plain li texts to clickable links with pure javascript, randomly

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic list of things. How to select only 3 items (that has 2 words or less) randomly, and convert it to clickable links. So everytimes the page is reloaded, random 3 links are created. Im expecting to use something like:

`innerHTML = '<a href="mysite.com/folder/' + url + text.toLowerCase().replace(/\bamp\b|[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "-") + '">' + text + '</a>'`

From this:

> list 1
>
> list 2 222
>
> list 3
>
> list 4
>
> list 5 555
>
> list ..
>
> list 99
>
> list 100

To this:

> - list 1
> - list 2 222 (*ignore 3 or more words)
> - list 3 (*selected randomly and pointed to mysite.com/folder/list-3)
> - list 4 (*selected randomly and pointed to mysite.com/folder/list-3)
> - list 5 55 (*ignore 3 or more words)
> - list ..
> - list 99 (*selected randomly and pointed to mysite.com/folder/list-99)
> - list 100

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the code that builds the dynamic list? Where is the html (at the very least) that shows the list? It's hard to help you because you really haven't given us anything to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the page has loaded, loop three times, each time grabbing a random `li` and refreshing that grab until it meets the criteria of having fewer than three words and not having been used yet. Each time you find an `li` that is valid, change the `innerHTML`.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var randomLI;
    while (!randomLI || randomLI.getElementsByTagName("a").length > 0 || randomLI.innerHTML.trim().split(" ").length > 2) {
      randomLI = rando(document.getElementsByTagName("li")).value;
    }

    randomLI.innerHTML = "<a href=\"mysite.com/folder/" + randomLI.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/\bamp\b|[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "-") + "\">" + randomLI.innerHTML + "</a>";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>list 1</li>
  <li>list 2 222</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
  <li>list 4</li>
  <li>list 5 555</li>
  <li>list ..</li>
  <li>list 99</li>
  <li>list 100</li>
</ul>
```

I used [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to simplify the randomness and make it more readable. If you want to use this code, make sure this is in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up the code a bit, but below can get you started.

Try the live demo at https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/povOJJP

```html
<!-- Your list here. -->

<ul class="listItems">
  <li>list 1</li>
  <li>list 2 222</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
  <li>list 4</li>
  <li>list 5 555</li>
  <li>list ..</li>
  <li>list 99</li>
  <li>list 100</li>
</ul>

<!-- Button to refresh the list -->
<button class="refresh">Refresh</button>
```

```js
// Store the DOM elements in variables
const ul = document.querySelector('.listItems');
const listItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.listItems li'));

// Check if three items with links are present, otherwise run the logic again
function updateList(list, pickCount) {
  if (pickCount === 3) {
    ul.innerHTML = list.join(' ');
  } else {
    randomize();
  }
}

function randomize() {
  let pickCount = 0;

  // Iterate over the list array to transform the items
  const newList = listItems.map(item => {

  // 50% chance of picking the item to include link
  const isPicked = Math.random() > .5 ? true : false;

  // Check if the item contains two or more words
  if (item.innerHTML.split(' ').length > 2 ) { 
    // If containing more than two words, skip.
    return item.outerHTML;
  } else if (isPicked) {
    // If containing two or less words, and passed the random pick, transform the item
    pickCount += 1;
    return `<li><a href="#">${item.innerHTML}</a></li>`;
  } else {
    // Otherwise, skip.
    return item.outerHTML;
  }
});

  return updateList(newList, pickCount);

}


document.querySelector('button.refresh').addEventListener('click', randomize);
```